# TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed for simple pd.query()

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that I am trying to run a `df.query()` on to simply find all the values where the column is not null. I am using a proxy df here and in this case trying to find `animal` column where it is not null (in this case it should be all). Both columns are objects.

My df looks as such:

```
   isin  animal
0  red   5473
1  nan   8829
2  red   9382
3  blue  7738
```

My query looks as such:

```
df.query("animal.notnull()")
```

However I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

I looked at the unique values and all values for `animal` and they are all string values.

I don't understand the error?

Comment: what happens if you write df.query("animal <> '' ") 
If your column is string type it cannot be null it can only be an empty string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a BUG refered as [`#34251`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/34251).

I can't reproduce the issue with `pandas 1.5.2` by the way :

```
print(df.query("animal.notnull()"))

   isin  animal
0   red    5473
1   nan    8829
2   red    9382
3  blue    7738
```

Try to set `python` as an *engine* :

```
print(df.query("animal.notnull()", engine="python"))
```

Otherwise, if the error persists, *upgrade* :

```
pip install --upgrade pandas
```